# Is there a way to redefine a method within a block?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I wanted to `puts` a large number of strings *in uppercase*, but for brevity, I wanted to write `puts(string)` instead of `puts(string.upcase)` each time.

Is there a way for me to redefine `puts` **within a block only**, like this?

```rb
# This will puts as normal
puts "abc"
# => abc

# This will puts an upcased string, but it's too verbose
puts "abc".upcase
# => ABC

# I want to do something like this, which will override the puts method for code run within the block
def always_upcase_strings(&block)
  def puts(string)
    super(string.upcase)
  end
end

always_upcase_strings do 
  puts "abc"
  puts "def"
  puts "ghi"
end
puts "xyz"
# => ABC
# => DEF
# => GHI
# => xyz
```

My example above is simplified - I'm not using `puts` in my case, but a method that I wrote myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [second thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929260/1954610), here's a better answer:

```
def always_upcase_strings(&block)
  anon_class = Class.new do
    def puts(str)
      super(str.upcase)
    end
  end
  anon_class.new.instance_eval(&block)
end

always_upcase_strings do
  puts "abc" #=> "ABC"
  puts "def" #=> "DEF"
  puts "ghi" #=> "GHI"
end

puts "xyz"   #=> "xyz"
```

This [creates](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) a temporary class (anonymous, because it has no need for a name) with the desired method override.

The yielded block is then invoked, **within the context of this class instance**.

As well as being less confusing than my "redefine-undefine-redefine the method" solution, this approach has the added advantage that it's *thread-safe*. So you won't get weird behaviour if, for example, running parallel tests whilst invoking the method.

...But I still stand by my original statement that redefining methods within a block is super surprising behaviour. Coworkers probably won't like you for choosing that design pattern (unless it's done in a limited manner, and for good reason!)

Comment: It even works without a class: `obj = Object.new`, then `def obj.puts ...` and finally `obj.instance_eval(&block)` The downside with the `instance_eval` approach however is that `self` will change within the block, which may break wrapped code. Using `method_missing` to delegate non-overridden methods to the original receiver could work, but then it's getting complex again.

Comment: I would prefer an approach like this to the first one (and echo all of your disclaimers). This `instance_eval` stuff is how FactoryBot gets their clean DSL. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/99ac02400fd56bd1872fc3ed84f81ea5e8f27737/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb#L49

Answer (score 1):

This is more-than-a-little-bit crazy; I don't recommend running anything like this in production... But I was curious, and found a way to do this with ruby's meta-programming:

```
def always_upcase_strings(&block)
  original_puts = method(:puts)
  define_method(:puts) do |string|
    original_puts.call(string.upcase)
  end
  yield
  undef :puts
  define_method(:puts, original_puts.unbind)
end

always_upcase_strings do
  puts "abc" #=> "ABC"
  puts "def" #=> "DEF"
  puts "ghi" #=> "GHI"
end

puts "xyz"   #=> "xyz"
```

What's going on here?

- First, I grab the `puts` [`Method` object](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html), and store it in a variable.
- Then, re-define `puts` to [invoke it](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call) with the desired modification. (You could also do this with `super(string.upcase)`, but the above better illustrates what's going on, I think.)
- Then `yield` to a block, so you can call the new version of the method.
- Next, `undef` the method (!!!), to completely get rid of the override. (But unfortunately this removes the original method, too. So...)
- Finally, [re-define the `puts` method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) by [re-binding the orignal](https://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html) back to `self`.

This is absolute black magic. Use at your own peril.

---

My "real world" advice would, instead, be:

```
def puts_upcase(str)
  puts str.upcase
end

puts_upcase "abc" #=> "ABC"
puts "xyz"        #=> "xyz"
```

Or maybe in your scenario, if you'd actually like to tweak a class method's behaviour, perhaps [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) is a better tool for the job.

The simpler solutions are often the better ones.

Comment: Do you really need `undef :puts` and the call to `unbind`? Just calling `define_method(:puts, original_puts)` to restore the original methods seem to be enough.

Comment: Aye you could. Except this does mean you're "polluting" Kernel with more and more definitions of puts, every time you call the method.

Comment: Do you? I thought that it would simply replace the former definition.